# How to Boot android bbbandroid from internal mmc?

Tags: android, linux, beagleboneblack, u-boot

I want to boot android pre-built bbbandroid.img.xz from internal mmc its always fail to boot whereas same procedure for SD Card it boot successfully.

To flash this image into internal mmc, I boot from SD Card and find internal memory at /dev/mmcblk1. Following command I used to flash image

```
sudo xz -cd bbbandroid.img.xz > /dev/mmcblk1
```

It shows partitions correctly. But always on console only slowly CCCCC printing and stopped.

Same procedure I am following to flash image into SD Card using UBuntu host machine and sd card reader and use similar command from ubuntu host machine

```
sudo xz -cd bbbandroid.img.xz > /dev/sdc
```

For Sd card, everything ok and booting successfully

I compared partitions of SD Card and internal mmc looks exactly same.

What might be problem any have idea?

Comment: One image is not going to be bootable from two devices that have different device addresses.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Can I get these information because I am trying get it but not getting anywhere. If same image cannot be used from different devices(mmc0/mmc1), why bone-debian-7.5-2014-05-14-2gb.img.xz I am able run from both device mmc0 and mmc1. I am following same method to deploy?

Comment: Anyone have idea to boot pre-built android image from internal mmc?